# wordpress how to make a snapshot/clone from production to development server

Tags: wordpress

How can I make a clone/snapshot or import or export to make a exact copy of production website to development machine? I only have access to admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the functionality of this [plugin wp-staging](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-staging/)